# Reformatting Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that when exported to csv looks like this:

```
                  VAL1    VAL2
10/2/2014         3.0      2.0
10/3/2014         5.0      4.0
```

I want it to look like this though:

```
      Date        VAL1     VAL2
1   10/2/2014      3.0     2.0
2   10/3/2014      5.0     4.0
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `reset_index()`. Something like:

```
data_frame.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

You may also need to `rename()` to change the columns if `Date` isn't the name of your column.

Comment: When I do `data_frame.reset_index()` nothing happens. Also tried `data_frame = data_frame.columns['Date', 'Val1', 'Val2']`, which gets me an invalid literal error, and `data_frame = data_frame.rename(columns = {'Date', 'Val1', 'Val2'})`, which gets me a set object not callable error.

Comment: @user2253332 Nothing happens after the `reset_index()`? What is `date_frame.dtypes`?

Comment: Oops sorry it works after data_frame.reset_index(), I was looking at the incorrect output.

Comment: @user2253332 when you can call `reset_index()` are you assigning back to your original dataframe? e.g. `df = df.reset_index()` you could also do `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: @user2253332 Excellent. It sounds like this works then.

Comment: @user2253332 Also note that when reading the csv back into pandas you can tell it to treat the first column as the index `df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv', index_col=[0])`

Comment: Perhaps @chrisaycock can merge these comments into his answer?